# Where does the data go once you've done rethinkdb restore

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

After I've used `rethinkdb restore`, where does rethinkdb import that data / access that data from?

I've tried searching for this answer, but my choice in keywords to use must be inadequate.

I want to use this directory as a shared volume for my docker container so the docker container is "separate" from the data but also has w/r access to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It imports into the data directory. Which is, by default, folder `rethinkdb_data` in working directory where you execute `rethinkdb`. Unless you specify a different with `-d`.

> $ rethinkdb -h
>
> Running 'rethinkdb' will create a new data directory or
>   use an existing one,   and serve as a RethinkDB cluster node. File
>   path options:   -d [ --directory ] path                     specify
>   directory to store data and
>                                                 metadata

If you are using Docker, and you didn't change the data directory with `-d`, then it's probably is store in 'rethinkdb_data`in your`WORKDIR` instruction in Dockerfile. You can mount it outside for persistent.

Take this image as example: https://github.com/stuartpb/rethinkdb-dockerfiles/blob/master/trusty/2.1.4/Dockerfile, it's official RethinkDB docker https://hub.docker.com/_/rethinkdb/

We can see that it has instruction:

```
WORKDIR /data
```

And it runs with:

```
CMD ["rethinkdb", "--bind", "all"]
```

Therefore, it store data in `/data/rethinkdb_data`. You can either mount the whole `/data` or only `/data/rethinkdb_data`/